# Mobile Safari shows no scrollbars on textarea

Tags: css, textarea, mobile-safari, scrollbars

I get no visible scrollbars on the y axis with the following class

```
.bodyTextBox
     {
        height: 150px;
        width: 225px;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        padding: 10px;
     }
```

while every other browser works fine.

Any info is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that's the way iPhone works. You have to place TWO fingers inside the textarea and then move them up or down to scroll. Very weird.

Comment: Thanks for this, never would have known about that trick otherwise.

Comment: In order to convey that this option exists, I have used a text box which is specifically sized to show that text overflows the box, ie: if you have more than 10+ lines: `height: 9.5em`